How do I cast Arc<RwLock<dyn Child>> to Arc<RwLock<dyn Base>>
I currently have some code like the following:
use std::sync::{Arc, RwLock};

// Define traits
trait Child: Base {
    fn method_a(&self);
}

trait Base {
    fn method_b(&self);
}

// Struct implementing both traits
struct MyStruct {
    something: i32,
};

impl Child for MyStruct {
    fn method_a(&self) {
        println!("Method A");
    }
}

impl Base for MyStruct {
    fn method_b(&self) {
        println!("Method B");
    }
}

fn do_some_processing(parent: &Arc<RwLock<dyn Child>>) -> Arc<RwLock<dyn Base>> {
    //How do i do this?
}

fn main() {
    let my_struct = Arc::new(RwLock::new(MyStruct));

    let base = do_some_processing(&my_struct);

}

I want to limit the functions used after do_some_processing has been called. That is the reason for the two traits.

By the way, any caller of do_some_processing would still be able to access the original as dyn Child since nothing here prevents them from keeping the original Arc around.

@kmdreko that is an interesting point thanks for letting me know.

Upcasting coercion is not yet stable. So this could work in +nightly
#![feature(trait_upcasting)]
use std::sync::{Arc, RwLock};

// Define traits
trait Child: Base {
    fn method_a(&self);
}

trait Base {
    fn method_b(&self);
}

// Struct implementing both traits
struct MyStruct {
    something: i32,
}

impl Child for MyStruct {
    fn method_a(&self) {
        println!("Method A");
    }
}

impl Base for MyStruct {
    fn method_b(&self) {
        println!("Method B");
    }
}

fn do_some_processing(parent: &Arc<RwLock<dyn Child>>) -> Arc<RwLock<dyn Base>> {
    parent.clone()
}



fn main() {
    let my_struct: Arc<RwLock<dyn Child>> = Arc::new(RwLock::new(MyStruct { something: 42 }));

    let base = do_some_processing(&my_struct);

}

---OR---
If you want to stick to stable you will need some wrapper
use std::sync::{Arc, RwLock};

// Define traits
trait Child: Base {
    fn method_a(&self);
}

trait Base {
    fn method_b(&self);
}

// Struct implementing both traits
struct MyStruct {
    something: i32,
}

impl Child for MyStruct {
    fn method_a(&self) {
        println!("Method A");
    }
}

impl Base for MyStruct {
    fn method_b(&self) {
        println!("Method B");
    }
}

// Wrapper struct to manually upcast Child to Base
struct BaseWrapper {
    inner: Arc<RwLock<dyn Child>>,
}

impl Base for BaseWrapper {
    fn method_b(&self) {
        self.inner.read().unwrap().method_b();
    }
}

fn upcast(child: Arc<RwLock<dyn Child>>) -> Arc<RwLock<dyn Base>> {
    Arc::new(RwLock::new(BaseWrapper { inner: child }))
}

fn main() {
    let my_struct: Arc<RwLock<dyn Child>> = Arc::new(RwLock::new(MyStruct { something: 42 }));

    let base = upcast(my_struct);

    base.read().unwrap().method_b();
}


The work-around should come with a big, fat, disclaimer: it's no longer transactional. That is, normally I can (1) lock, (2) call method A, (3) call method B, and (4) unlock, and I am assured that nothing happened in-between the calls to A & B. On the other hand, with the work-around, because the lock on inner is released after each forwarding call, another thread could lock and modify the object between the calls. Not necessarily a problem now... but definitely could come and bite the maintainers later on.
